# How do I adjust a Div height based on viewport size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the `#maincontent` div to be able to scroll and the rest of the divs to remain stationary.

When I try the following code I get the desired effect, however the `#maincontent` div extends further down then the actual viewport and I am unable to read the remaining text.  I would like the height of the `#maincontent` to adjust depending on the viewport but nothing else to adjust.

**CSS**

```
#framecontentTop{
    position: inherit;
    top: 5px;
    left: 0px; /*Set left value to WidthOfLeftFrameDiv 220px*/
    right: 200px; /*Set right value to WidthOfRightFrameDiv*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 175px;
    overflow: hidden; /*Disable scrollbars. Set to "scroll" to enable*/
    background-color: #8b45130;
}

#maincontent{
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 175px; /*Set top value to HeightOfTopFrameDiv*/
    height: 100%;
    left: 220px; /*Set left value to WidthOfLeftFrameDiv*/
    right: 205px; /*Set right value to WidthOfRightFrameDiv*/
    width: 500px;
    bottom: 0px;
    overflow: auto; 
    background: #fff;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){
    var parent= $('#maincontent');
    var parentOffset = parent.offset();
    var bottom = 0; 
    parent.find('*').each(function() {
        var elem = $(this);
        var elemOffset = elem.offset();
        var elemBottom = elemOffset.top + elem.outerHeight(true) - parentOffset.top;
        if (elemBottom > bottom) {
            bottom = elemBottom;
        }
    });
    parent.css('min-height', bottom);
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been frustrated with this code for some time now.

Comment: height 100% + top 175px?  of course your div goes below the viewport.  Just remove the height as you have set bottom:0

Comment: Please provide the HTML markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it by using

```
box-sizing: border-box
```

example:-

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html,body {
  height:100%;
}

#framecontentTop{
    top: 5px;
    left: 0px; /*Set left value to WidthOfLeftFrameDiv 220px*/
    right: 200px; /*Set right value to WidthOfRightFrameDiv*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 175px;
    overflow: hidden; /*Disable scrollbars. Set to "scroll" to enable*/
    background-color: #8b45130;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}

#maincontent{
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative; 
    top: -180px; /*Negative Set top value to HeightOfTopFrameDiv + position*/
    padding-top: 180px /*Set padding-top value to HeightOfTopFrameDiv + position*/
    height: 100%;
    left: 220px; /*Set left value to WidthOfLeftFrameDiv*/
    right: 205px; /*Set right value to WidthOfRightFrameDiv*/
    width: 500px;
    overflow: auto; 
    background: #fff;
}
```

The important part is to set the `top` to negative value of the `#framecontentTop` and applying `padding-top` to shift the content of the `#maincontent` to the correct position.

And since the elements are overlapping, it needs correction by applying z-index to the `#framecontentTop`

This is a sample for reference:- http://jsbin.com/neweyozamiha/2

Comment: Thank you!  This got the desired length of the #maincontent Div however now I get the scroll bars through the header of the page.  Is there a way to get the scroll bars to only show in the content section?

Comment: @gwisher make the `#maincontent` `overscroll:hidden` and add a div inside the `#maincontent`, make that div scrollable, with height set to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the vh unit on your height. For example:

```
#maincontent{
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 175px; /*Set top value to HeightOfTopFrameDiv*/
    height: 100vh; // USE VH HERE
    left: 220px; /*Set left value to WidthOfLeftFrameDiv*/
    right: 205px; /*Set right value to WidthOfRightFrameDiv*/
    width: 500px;
    bottom: 0px;
    overflow: auto; 
    background: #fff;
}
```

This says that the main content element will be 100% of the current view point height.

There is a support issue though so if you need it to work below IE9 then you will have to try a different method.

[Here is the support in more detail.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

Answer (score 0):

With absolute positioning, since you have top and bottom set, there's no need to set the height. Assuming that the nearest relative or absolutely positioned parent of #maincontent is the page body, setting bottom to 0 should work for you, without having to use javascript.

```
#maincontent{
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 175px; /*Set top value to HeightOfTopFrameDiv*/
  /*height: 100%;*/
  left: 220px; /*Set left value to WidthOfLeftFrameDiv*/
  right: 205px; /*Set right value to WidthOfRightFrameDiv*/
  width: 500px;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto; 
  background: #fff;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bxos3tx3/

Another alternative might be to have the page content be relatively positioned, but then do fixed positioning on the other elements (makes their position relative to the viewport, rather than other elements)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't give it a `height` or `width` but *do* give it a `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` positions then the element's size is automatically 100% of its bounds.

```css
html,body {height:100%; min-height:100%; background-color:grey; padding:0; margin:0;}
#maincontent{
    padding:10px;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 175px; /*Set top value to HeightOfTopFrameDiv*/
    left: 220px; /*Set left value to WidthOfLeftFrameDiv*/
    right: 205px; /*Set right value to WidthOfRightFrameDiv*/
    bottom:0px;
    overflow: auto; 
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="maincontent">
<p>Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor.</p><p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit.</p><p>Donec sed odio dui. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.</p>
</div>
```